# Getting a SyntaxError when loading API

Tags: javascript, api, kongregate

I load kongregate_api script in the head of the html document like this

```html
<script src='https://cdn1.kongregate.com/javascripts/kongregate_api.js'></script>
```

Then loading my main.js script that contains these lines

```js
    console.log(window.kongregateAPI)
    window.kongregateAPI.loadAPI(function () {});
```

[image: screenshot of a part of main.js]

The error message;

**SyntaxError**: An invalid or illegal string was specified 
*in kongregate_api.js:36*

*console.log* returns and object so i think it loads the script successfully.

[image: screenshot of console logs]

Answer (score -1):

**Loading the API**

In order to load the Kongregate API object, you need to include a script tag which loads our JavaScript source file. The script tag should be placed inside the head section of your document.

**HTML**

```
<script src='https://cdn1.kongregate.com/javascripts/kongregate_api.js'></script>
```

**Initializing the API**

The JavaScript API automatically creates a global variable named kongregateAPI. You can use this object to initialize the Kongregate API services with the loadAPI and the getAPI functions:

**Example**: Load the API, and set up a global reference to the API object named kongregate function once initialized.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
kongregateAPI.loadAPI(function(){
  window.kongregate = kongregateAPI.getAPI();
  // You can now access the Kongregate API with:
  // kongregate.services.getUsername(), etc
  // Proceed with loading your game...
});
```

**Note**
*The API should only be loaded/initialized once per Kongregate game page load. If your application spans multiple pages/documents, please see the documentation on the Kongregate Shell for information on setting up and accessing a persistent API connection*

Comment: This is exactly how it is decribed in the kongregate javascript api page. But i still can not see the problem in my code. [Kongregate JS API Page](https://docs.kongregate.com/docs/javascript-api)